# Why setText can't work in handleKeyPress?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
<TextInput onFocus={handleTextInputFocus}
            value={text}
            onChangeText={setText}
            onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
/>
const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.key === 'Enter') {
      let content = text;
      setText('');
      (async () => {
        setText('');
        try {
          const data = await FetchFromBackend(
            SendGroupMessagesRequest({ user_id, group_id, content })
          );
          if (data.data.ActionStatus === 'FAIL') {
            return;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(err.message);
        }
      })();
    }
  };
```

Why setText can't work ? I can't figure it out. Only when I place `setText('')` at the end of the 'if' block can work. Any help would be really amazing thank you

Comment: What kind of output you expect from this.